# Django Tastypie API remote access

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a django tastypie API and i want to access to the API's resource via a remote host but i cant retrieve data!

I proceed with an ajax call for retrieving data it works great on the local machine but fails when i connect via another machine

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/actors/',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        type : 'GET',
        data : { format: 'jsonp' },
        success : function(data) {                
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the document you are running the code above on a different domain than the `url` requested?

Comment: The document are located in my apache directory /var/www and i access to them via my phone!

Comment: What is the url of the document with the ajax, and what's the `url` attribute you pass to the `$.ajax` in that document?

Comment: I access to the document with this address `http://localhost/project/actors.html` and the **url** i dont pass attribute to the $.ajax i just specify the data format to return! `?format=jsonp`

Comment: Change the url to `http://localhost/api/v1/actors/` in your `$.ajax` call and see what happens.

Comment: i got an error 404 with this url!

Answer (score 0):

Use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to allow cross-domain XMLHttpRequests requests

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i finally solved my problem by overiding my Resource class in the API for allowing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to accept all origin and by changing my url to **http://192.168.1.XX/api/v1/actors/**!